# entity framework core migrations do not work with class library, yet?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

I have an asp.net core project 'Api' with target:

```
<TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
```

That project references another class library project 'Repository' with target:

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
```

The 'Api' project has this configured:

```
services
.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
    b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Repository"))
)
.AddScoped(p => new ApplicationDbContext(p.GetService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()));
```

When I am in the PMConsole I enter:

Add-Migration Initial

then I get this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
add-migration : Exception calling "Substring" with "1" argument(s): "StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex"
At line:1 char:1
+ add-migration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException,Add-Migration
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EF Core commands only work for startup projects, i.e. something that can actually *run*, as opposed to a class library. This is because the context is created via dependency injection, which can only occur during runtime. A workaround is to create an implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` in your class library. When the commands see your implementation, that factory will then be used to instantiate the context.

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("[connection string here]");

        return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

For more information, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation).

Comment: I had no probs with .net core libraries.

Comment: My context was being created fine from a startup project but my dbcontext is defined in a class library and I've done the contextfactory as shown but when I run Add-Migration I start to get the error as described by the OP.  Any idea what is actually causing the ArgumentOutOfRangeException?